# Website too slow

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Sometimes my website takes a long time to load, from different pages, different devices and browsers, it takes more than a minute, sometimes it show the content and sometimes 500 Internal Error, and other website are displayed.

I uploaded the website in 2 different servers, it is the same thing, and the servers are mine, no other websites hosted.

I can get theses errors from error.log:

```
105.151.122.22 - - [25/Nov/2015:07:08:21 +0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
105.151.122.22 - - [25/Nov/2015:07:08:21 +0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
105.151.122.22 - - [25/Nov/2015:07:08:22 +0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
105.151.122.22 - - [25/Nov/2015:07:08:22 +0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
105.151.122.22 - - [25/Nov/2015:07:08:22 +0300] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
::1 - - [25/Nov/2015:07:08:25 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

and theses from access.log:

```
[Wed Nov 25 07:09:13.008575 2015] [:error] [pid 14972] [client 105.151.122.22:55678] PHP Stack trace:
[Wed Nov 25 07:09:13.008608 2015] [:error] [pid 14972] [client 105.151.122.22:55678] PHP   1. {main}() /home/alfirdaouscom/www/index.php:0
[Wed Nov 25 07:09:13.008645 2015] [:error] [pid 14972] [client 105.151.122.22:55678] PHP   2. require_once() /home/alfirdaouscom/www/index.php:6170
```

Hence while is not loading, I can access the server via SSH and I can upload files easily.

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Http 408 errors are often difficult to resolve, these are basically  "Request Timeout" . You need to check workload on the Web server when they occur. 
Check this link https://serverfault.com/questions/383290/too-many-408-error-codes-in-access-log